# Angular.js, repeat in form and submit POST values

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular.js and am trying to figure out how to get the data from a form on submit. But the fields are part of an ng-repeat. At the moment when I submit using ajaxSubmitButton, to a php server side script which only displays the post values, it only shows the last of the input fields...if that makes any sense.
Here is the form code:

```
<form class="form">
<div id="client-form" ng:controller="ClientForm">
  <div class="client" ng:repeat="client in form.clients">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="client.name" size="80" />
    </div>
  </div>

<div>
    <?php echo  CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                    'Submit',
                    CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('client/create.php')),
                    array(
                        'success'=>'function(data){
                            alert("success:"+data);
                        }',
                    )
                ); ?>
</div>
```

The JavaScript is as follows:

```
<script src="'/js/angular.min.js'; ?>" ng:autobind></script>
<script>
function ClientForm(){
  this.form = {
    clients : [
      { name: 'test1', },
      { name: 'test2', },
      { name: 'test3', },
    ]
  };

}
</script>
```

And the PHP script is very simple:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

The alert in the ajaxSubmitButton call returns the following:

```
success:Array
(
  [client]=>test3
)
```

As you can see it is only returning the value of the last input text field.

I am sure there must be something I am doing wrong here, but can't seem to see it. Any guidance would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer to this thanks to someone on IRC for Yii - can't remember your name but thanks!
Basically I had to change the name attribute of the fields to be an array.

```
<input name="client[name][]" value="{{client.name}}" />
```

This now works perfectly for text fields.
But for a select dropdown it no longer selects the predefined value.

```
<form class="form">
<div id="client-form" ng:controller="ClientForm">
  <div class="client" ng:repeat="client in form.clients">
    <div class="row">
      <input name="client[name][]" value="{{client.name}}" /><input name="client[id][]" value="{{client.id}}" />
      <?php
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('client[select][]', '{{client.select}}', CHtml::listData(Region::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'name')), 'id', 'name'), array('empty' => 'Select a Region'));
      ?>{{client.id}}
    </div>
  </div>

<div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/angular.min.js'; ?>" ng:autobind></script>
<script>
function ClientForm(){
  this.form = {
    clients : [
      { name: 'test1', id:'1', select:'1'},
      { name: 'test2', id:'2', select:'2'},
      { name: 'test3', id:'3', select:'3'},
    ]
  };

}
</script>
```

Any idea how to ensure my select list is now prepopulated?

Thanks.